# Shell script for kill command

Tags: path, kill, chmod, which

I'm following a tutorial on using text editors and one exercise was to make a "safer" kill command script. I made a `~/bin` directory. Then made the following kill command script called `ekill`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Kill a process as safely as possible.
# Tries to kill a process using a series of signals with escalating urgency.
# usage: ekill <pid>

# Assign the process id to the first argument.
pid=$1
kill -15 $pid || kill -2 $pid || kill -1 $pid || kill -9 $pid
```

I created my `~/bin` path by using an export on my `~/.bash_profile`. Then it asked to chmod ekill so I typed: `chmod +x ~/bin/ekill`. Afterwards I typed the command `which ekill`, but it looks like my chmod didn't work because the which command didn't show my ekill path.

Comment: I think I see one of your problems, but to get assistance with anything, you should provide the command you type and the exact error it returns.  This way people won't go beating around the bush all day long.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, if that kill script is really what your tutorial shows you, it might be a good idea to look for a better one because sending these signals at micro-second intervals won't be different then just sending the `kill -9 $pid` directly.

Comment: Did you `source .bash_profile` after making the modifications?

Comment: Hey Julie, thank you for responding. Okay so besides my script, I created my path on ~/.bash_profile: `export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"` After I created my path I typed `chmod +x ~/bin/ekill` and it returned nothing. I then type: `which ekill` on my home directory to get the path but nothing came back. I look in ~/bin directory and ekill is in there.

Comment: yes, once i `source .bash_profile` I typed `echo $PATH` and the output was `~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'

Comment: Can you run it as `~/bin/ekill`?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Actually, it's equivalent to `kill -15` unless the process isn't running when the script starts but starts just between the time `kill -15` fails and the time `kill -2` is tried. The `kill` command succeeds as long as the PID is valid and the caller has the right privileges, so under normal circumstances, the `|| …` part never runs. Either way, it's silly. The “safer” kill command would be `kill -15 $1; sleep 1; kill -2 $1` etc. except that it's dangerous because it might kill an unrelated process — `kill` doesn't give any feedback as to whether the process dies.

Comment: @Rio6 It seems to terminate processes fine. I'm just a little bothered/annoyed that it doesn't show me the path my ekill script is on. I type `which ekill` and it should return `~/bin/ekill` but nothing comes back

Comment: Maybe you need to use `$HOME/bin/` instead of `~/bin`

Comment: @Rio6 Thank you! that worked, now I just need to find out why it didn't work for `~/bin` but it worked for `$HOME/bin/`....

Comment: @Gilles:  Your point (better alternative) is close to what I meant but I apparently didn't make it clear enough.  The first kill should give the process time to react.

Answer (score 2):

add this to the top of you script :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

you should add your `~/bin` to your `PATH` variable.

In your `.profile` add this line :

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

source your `.profile`

```
source ~/.profile
```

after execute `which ekill`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I need to edit my post, I did have the #!/bin/bash on top of my script (forgot to indent).

Comment: As for my PATH variable I wrote: export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"